# Do not display images and files in react (MERN STACK)

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express

I can't display the images in the frontend

I used multiter and tried to store only the name of the image in the database, but to no avail. I tried to make a page and predict what would happen. I tried artificial intelligence, but to no avail.

this a front end (react)

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import {
  MDBIcon
} from 'mdb-react-ui-kit';
import '../card/card.css';
import Carinfo from '../comp/carinfo';
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

function Cars() {
  const [cars, setCars] = useState([]);
  const [query, setQuery] = useState("");
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData() {
      try {
        const response = await fetch('http://localhost:7000/images');
        const data = await response.json();
        setCars(data.files);
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    }
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <div className="search-input">
        <a href="#" target="_blank" hidden />
        <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="Search cars"
          onChange={(event) => setQuery(event.target.value)}
        />
        <div className="icon">
          <i className="fas fa-search" />
        </div>
      </div>

      <h1 id="cars-title">
        Cars <MDBIcon fas icon="car" />
      </h1>

      <div className="card-container">
        {cars &&
          cars
            .filter((car) => {
              if (query === '') {
                return car;
              } else if (car.carName.toLowerCase().includes(query.toLowerCase())) {
                return car;
              }
            })
            .map((car) => (
              <div className="img-card iCard-style1" key={car._id}>
                <div className="card-content">
                  <div className="card-image">
                    <h1 className="card-title">{car.carName}</h1>
                    <img src={car.carImg} alt="img" />
                  </div>
                  <div className="card-text">
                    <h3>{car.carType}</h3>
                    <h3 className="year">car Year: {car.carYear}</h3>
                    <h6 className="km">{car.carColor}</h6>
                    <span className="price">
                      price is: <h4>{car.carPrice}$</h4>
                    </span>
                    <h5 className="km">
                      {car.carKm} km <i className="fa-solid fa-gauge" />
                    </h5>
                    <h6 className="carD">{car.carDescription}</h6>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div className="card-link">
                  <button
                    id="btn-card"
                    onClick={() =>
                      navigate('/Carinfo', {
                        state: {
                          carName: car.carName,
                          carYear: car.carYear,
                          carPrice: car.carPrice,
                          carKm: car.carKm,
                          carColor: car.carColor,
                          carImg: car.carImg,
                          carDescription: car.carDescription,
                          carType: car.carType,
                        },
                      })
                    }
                  >
                    <span id="read">Read Full</span>
                  </button>
                </div>
              </div>
            ))}
      </div>
    </>
  );
}


export default Cars;
```

backend

```
//  var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const { MongoClient } = require('mongodb');

var url = "mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/";
var express = require('express');
const multer = require('multer');
const dbName = "cars";
const collectionName = "car-name";
const app = express();
var local = 7000;
app.use(express.json());
var express = require('express');
var upload = multer();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');



// CORS Headers => Required for cross-origin/ cross-server communication
//this for set data to front end react to Allow
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.setHeader(
    'Access-Control-Allow-Headers',
    'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization'
  );
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'PUT,GET, POST, PATCH, DELETE');

  next();
});

// for parsing application/json
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// for parsing application/xwww-
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
//form-urlencoded

// for parsing multipart/form-data
app.use(upload.array());
app.use(express.static('public'));



const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(null, 'C:/Users/tahaa/OneDrive/Desktop/yourcar edit/front-end/src/cars/');
  },
  filename: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(null, file.originalname);
  }
});

const upload1 = multer({ storage: storage });

app.post('/upload', upload1.single('file'), (req, res) => {
  try {
    const file = req.file;
    const carName = req.body.carName;
    const carType = req.body.carType;
    const carYear = req.body.carYear;
    const carColor = req.body.carColor;
    const carDescription = req.body.carDescription;
    const carPrice = req.body.carPrice;
    const carKm = req.body.carKm;

    MongoClient.connect(url, { useUnifiedTopology: true })
      .then((client) => {
        const db = client.db(dbName);
        const collection = db.collection(collectionName);
        const myobj = {
          carName: carName,
          carType: carType,
          carYear: carYear,
          carColor: carColor,
          carImg: file.filename, // Save only the filename in the database
          carDescription: carDescription,
          carPrice: carPrice,
          carKm: carKm
        };

        return collection.insertOne(myobj);
      })
      .then(() => {
        res.json({ message: 'File uploaded successfully!' });
        console.log('File uploaded successfully!');
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.error('Failed to save image path in MongoDB', err);
        res.status(500).json({ message: 'Failed to save image path in MongoDB' });
      });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Failed to upload file', error);
    res.status(500).json({ message: 'Failed to upload file' });
  }
});



app.get('/images', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const client = await MongoClient.connect(url, {
      useUnifiedTopology: true,
    });
    const database = client.db('cars');
    const inputs = database.collection('car-name');
    const count = await inputs.estimatedDocumentCount();

    if (count === 0) {
      return res.status(404).send({
        message: 'Error: No cars found',
      });
    }

    const result = await inputs.find({}).toArray();
    console.log(result);

    res.send({ files: result });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    res.status(500).send({
      message: 'Error: Something went wrong',
      error,
    });
  }

});

// app.listen(`Server listening on http://localhost:${local}`);
app.listen(local);
```

I've tried more than once, but unfortunately to no avail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've gone through your code. What you are doing is, you are uploading the file to your path `C:/Users/tahaa/OneDrive/Desktop/yourcar edit/front-end/src/cars/`, which I assume is your frontend code's path.

It is not relevant to save images from you backend server on your frontend code's path because it will work only on your local machine. If you deploy your code on a production server, then multer won't be able to save the file anywhere else other than the temp folder (only if you have any) on your node project directory due to server's restrictions.

There are 3 other ways you can achieve this -

- Save the Uploaded images to your `public` folder. Since you are using `express.static('public')` the node server will allow direct access to the files inside the public folder.
- Save the uploaded images in MongoDB in a base64 format. You have to convert the image into a base64 string to save. And upon retrieval send base64 from the API to the frontend and convert it into an image. (But this method has a drawback, base64 string is very large in size, and that can slow the API.)
- Use a third party storage service, like [Cloudinary](https://cloudinary.com/) or [AWS S3 Bucket](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/).